# Magento 2 - disabled module still apears in admin panel

Tags: magento2

- I disabled the custom module
- The disabled module was showing a textarea for the custom attribute in Category form
- However, after disabling the module, the textarea is still there. I can't get rid of it.

What I tried:

- setup:upgrade didn't help
- regenerating the admin template didn't help
- module:disable with --clear-static-content didn't help

Please let me know what I'm missing here. Thanks!

Comment: how to disable module to you ?

Comment: I finally made it work by manually deleting attribute in database. Weird....

Answer (score 0):

Go to Shops -> Configurations -> Advanced -> Advances Tab. You should see a list of all installed and running add-ons. Search for the Module that gives you bugs: `Vendor_Namespace`. If its still there, but its deleted on the filesystem, then it might just be a bug with the cache.

Before you start -- check for mistakes made:
Do you have a second folder of M2 running on your webserver? 
Which mode are you in? Developer or production? Switch to Developer if you haven't switched after install yet. You can do this via `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`. **Note**: if you have switched it before via this command, you might not wanna do it (the mode of the deployment of the files basically changes and a little other dev-stuff gets enabled).

Otherwise, proceed:

utilize bin/Magento via SSH.

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php setup:static-content:deploy`

If you have another, different language as backend user as en_US, add the specific flag to the deploy-paramter. I.e.: setup:static-content:deploy en_US de_DE fr_FR .._::`.

If this still doesn't work, try deleting the content of pub/static/. You can do this with:

`rm -rf pub/static/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*`, however, **never** delete pub/static (!!!) directly, always add the `/*` after it.

If the modules output is still there you should manually check the aboves folders. Also, set your chmod (664 for files, 755 for folders) in order to allow Magento to deploy correctly.

Comment: None of above worked. The module in not listed in Shops->Config->Adv->Adv. It is also phisically removed from web server. Static content rebuilt, folders cleared and it still there!!! Help!

Comment: I didn't downvote any answer. No idea why there are -1. It wasn't me.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

please run this command:

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

Flush the cache using the following command

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

It will solve your issue after you refresh the admin page.

Answer (score 0):

Please run these commands :

```
bin/magento cache:flush

sudo rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/* pub/static/frontend/ var/view_preprocessed/

bin/magento s:up
```

And then hard refresh

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps for disable Module:

1. check module status

   **bin/magento module:status**
2. If module is in enable list then run command

   **bin/magento module:disable Vendor_Extension**
3. then run

   **rm -rf generated/***
4. then flush the cache

   **bin/magento cache:flush**